# Add active class to current subcategory

Tags: php, magento

With the code blow I retrieve the current parent category and his children. Is it possible to add an active class for the current child?

```
<?php
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
    $loadCategory = $currentCat;
    }
    else
    {
    $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
    }
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
    if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'active class'?  A CSS class?  A PHP class?

Comment: I'm sorry Kevin. What I mean is a CSS class.

Comment: Are you trying to highlight (using a different css classname) the current subcategory?

Comment: Magento has built-in public method isCategoryActive http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#isCategoryActive Following your code try this (should work fine on categories' pages) if($this->isCategoryActive($cat)) {
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
        }
        else {
       echo  '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the current category, so you can check it's ID against the IDs of the categories being looped through.

Where you have

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
```

Change it to do the check for the ID and then add the "active" class when found

```
$class = '';
if ($currentCat->getId() == $cat->getId())
{
    $class = ' class="active"';
}
echo '<li'.$class.'><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the category as active we have to set the current category in catalog layer.

```
$_categoryName=YourCategoryName;

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', $_categoryName);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($_category);
```

This looks better than ugly hack of changing in phtml filter..